# In R data table, max works on an ordered factor and fails when grouped

Tags: r, data.table

The function `max()` operates correctly on column of type ordered factor. However, the same operation fails when the column is grouped with `by=`.

Let's say I have a data.table as:

```
DT <- data.table(ID=rep(1:3, 3), State=sample(LETTERS[1:3], 9, replace=TRUE))
```

Convert the column `State` to ordered factor as:

```
DT[, State := factor(State, levels=LETTERS[1:3], ordered = TRUE)]
```

This works:

```
DT[, max(State)]
```

This fails with error:

```
DT[, max(State), by="ID"]
```

Error is: Error in gmax(State) : max is not meaningful for factors.

How come?

Comment: This solves the problem, and I don't understand the mechanics of it. Please help. `DT[, min(ordered(State)), by="ID"]`

Comment: `DT[, max(ordered(State)), by="ID"]` is giving me an error, but `DT[, State[which.max(as.numeric(State))], by = ID]` works. Not sure why `DT[, max(State), by="ID"]` gives an error though, especially since `DT[, class(State), by = ID]` shows it's still an ordered factor after grouping.

Comment: @Ryan There are 6 rows in the query `DT[, class(State), by = ID]`. Not sure why that happens, or if it's relevant.

Comment: See `?GForce`. They just haven't coded it for ordered factors yet, I guess. Issue opened over here https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1947

Answer (score 4):

This was a bug that has been fixed in the current development version of `data.table`.

You can install the development version via:

```
install.packages('data.table', type = 'source',
                 repos = 'http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table')
```

If this fails, check full details on the [Installation wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

```
library(data.table)
# data.table 1.11.5 IN DEVELOPMENT built 2018-08-13 20:20:11 UTC; travis  Latest news: r-datatable.com
DT[ , max(State), by="ID"]
#    ID V1
# 1:  1  C
# 2:  2  C
# 3:  3  B
```

For those in controlled/production environments unable to update, you can still sidestep the problem by running:

```
dt_optim = options(datatable.optimize = 0) 
DT[ , max(State), by="ID"]
# resetting afterwards to keep your code running as fast as possible
options(datatable.optimize = dt_optim)
```

The bug came from `data.table`'s internally optimized grouping framework `GForce`; the above workaround stops this code from executing and defaults to `base::max`.